# How to enlarge an image with it's border colors

Tags: php, imagick

I'm scaling images for use on a website, but need a fixed size and aspect ratio. Imagick() can do the resizing, but I can't find a way to fill up the additional space with the border pixels like in this question: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34525. I looked through all examples here: https://phpimagick.com/Imagick, but they're not what I need.
Does anyone know a way to do this from PHP with the Imagick() class?
Thanks in advance!

Update because of a "non focused question": I need a solution to do just this with the Imagick() class in PHP:
[image: Example]

I have the following code to resize the image:

```
$im = new Imagick('myImage.png');
$im->resizeImage(900, 400, Imagick::FILTER_CATCOM, 0.9, true);
$im->extentImage(1600, 400, -350, 0);
```

This code resizes an original image of for example 450 x 200 pixels to 900 x 400 pixels and then extends it to 1600 x 400 pixels placing the resized image in the middle. This works as expected, but doesn't use the image's border pixels to extend the image.

Using $im->distort() as mentioned in the first comment should be the solution, but I can't figure out where to place it and what parameter(s) to use.

Comment: Seeing as the answer in that thread used a `distort` command, I'd wager that the PHP version would use the [`distort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.distortimage.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal (not very fast), but it does a better job than what I wanted.

```
$sImg = 'path/to/my/image'; /* 435 x 609 pixels in my example */
$iWidth = 880; /* width of the final image */
$iHeight = 584; /* height of the final image */
$nWidth = 417;  /* width of the scaled image */
$nHeight = 584; /* height of the scaled image */

# Open and resize the original image
$im = new Imagick($cfgClient[$client]['path']['frontend'] . $sImg);
$im->setImageOpacity(1.0);
$im->resizeImage($nWidth, $nHeight, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 0.9, true);

# Create a new image with the desired sizes
$im2 = new Imagick();
$im2->newImage($iWidth, $iHeight, 'none');
$im2->setImageFormat('png');
$im2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$im2->setImageOpacity(1.0);

# Copy the image scaled down from every corner
$im1 = new Imagick($sImg);
$im1->setImageOpacity(1.0);
if (($iWidth - $nWidth) > ($iHeight - $nHeight)) {
    $fFactor = (($iHeight == $nHeight) ? 0 : ((($iWidth - $nWidth) / 2) / (($iHeight - $nHeight) / 2)));
    for ($i = 0, $n = (($iWidth - $nWidth) / 2); $i <= $n; $i += 2) {
        $im1->adaptiveResizeImage(($iWidth - ($i * 2)), ($iHeight - ($i * $fFactor * 2)));
        $im2->compositeImage($im1, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $i, ($i * $fFactor));
    }
}
else {
    $fFactor = (($iWidth == $nWidth) ? 0 : ((($iHeight - $nHeight) / 2) / (($iWidth - $nWidth) / 2)));
    for ($i = 0, $n = (($iHeight - $nHeight) / 2); $i <= $n; $i += 2) {
        $im1->adaptiveResizeImage(($iWidth - ($i * $fFactor * 2)), ($iHeight - ($i * 2)));
        $im2->compositeImage($im1, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, ($i * $fFactor), $i);
    }
}
$im2->blurImage(1, 1);

# Copy the scaled image over the extended image
$im2->compositeImage($im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, (($iWidth - $nWidth) / 2), (($iHeight - $nHeight) / 2));

# Save the image
$im2->writeImage('path/to/new/file');

# Cleanup
unset($im, $im1, $im2);
```

This creates

[image: this]

from

[image: this]

If anyone can find a faster solution, please post it here.
Thanks!